# How do I use wildcards in Notepad++ to 'find and replace' all of this text?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I would really appreciate some help with this. I am working with a large corpus of text that has been marked-up with XML script and I need to tidy some things up. More specifically, there are several hundred numbers in square brackets (i.e., like '[1234]') that I need to delete (brackets included). Each number is different and there can be anything from 3 to 5 digits in these numbers.

The second thing I need to do is to place XML tags around some other pieces of text. These are names in round brackets. I.e., like:

He (Mr. Smith) said...

Which I want to change to:

He `<annot> (Mr. Smith) </annot>` said...'.

How can I perform both of these changes?

I've already tried using Extended Mode and searching for '[.*]', but it returns no hits. When I try the same with RegEx I get lots of hits, but it seems to be searching for each and every square bracket in the corpus.

Answer (score 1):

The square brackets are a special token in regular expressions (`[a-z]` means any character in the range `a` to `z`), so you'd have to escape them.

Your search expression would become `\[\d+\]` (with `\d+` meaning one or more digits). However you want to replace this with the digits alone. You need to setup a capturing group, using parentheses, and reference it in the replace expression. Your settings become:

- Search for: `\[(\d+)\]`
- Replace with: `\1`

As for your second problem, I'm not sure I understand it properly with the context you give... if only names are between parenthesis, you can just replace `\([^\)]+\)` with `<annot> \0 </annot>`, or maybe `\(Mr\. [^\)]+\)` if the names are preceded by `Mr.`.

To get into details, the way it works is so:

- the parenthesis you search for have to be escaped (as they are normally used to define capturing groups, so you use `\(` and `\)`
- `[^...]+` means one or more characters which is not `...`
- your search expression is therefore an opening parenthesis, followed by any characters which is not a closing parenthesis (so it should match the names), followed by a closing parenthesis.
- `\0` represents the whole searched expression in the replacement area

If you have a list of those names to replace, then you'd better use `\(whatever name\)` as the search expression, and if you don't, then it's impossible, as you can't make a regexp "guess" what's a name and what's not.

Comment: Also, you need to expilictly search using regex. Extended mode only does \t for tabs, \r \n for new lines, etc.